# jquery ui-dialog move from bottom of page to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Iam using ui-dialog ,by default it's a fixed and i get the html code at the end of page before  directly , how can i force it to append in a

```
 <div class="container"></div>
```

without to be fixed in page

[image: see the screenshot]

Comment: When you call the dialog from `jquery-ui`, this library need to add html in your source. At this point they chosed to put the dialog html before the closing `</body>`

Comment: Give your .container an id, then you can use:

    appendTo: "#yourContainingElement"

The default is to append it to the `body`.

See the docs: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#options

[edit: added as an answer because it will answer OPs question entirely]

Comment: Hi
i try to use is like
`$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    appendTo: "#yourContainingElement"
  });`
 but not works with me

Answer (score 0):

Give your .container an id, then you can use:

```
appendTo: "#yourContainingElement"
```

The default is to append it to the body.

See the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#options

Comment: Hi
i try to use is like
`$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    appendTo: "#yourContainingElement"
  });`
 but not works with me

Comment: You have actually got an element (div etc) with the id "yourContainingElement" if you've used that code verbatim?